# Regex library benchmark

Tags: regex, benchmarking

Is there an up-to-date benchmark of contemporary regex libraries? I'm interested in `re2`, `pcre` with jit, `NSRegularExpression`, `Irregexp`, etc.

I found http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml and [Regular expression library benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544225/regular-expression-library-benchmarks) both of wich are pretty outdated.

Edit:

I found another link:
https://github.com/axiak/pyre2#id6 (Chapter "Performance")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of benchmarks:

- [A comparison of regex engines – Rust Leipzig](https://rust-leipzig.github.io/regex/2017/03/28/comparison-of-regex-engines/)
- [It's just a simple regex benchmark of different programming languages.](https://github.com/mariomka/regex-benchmark)
- [re2r Benchmark](https://qinwenfeng.com/re2r_doc/benchmark.html)
- [Regex Engine Matching Speed Benchmark](http://openresty.org/misc/re/bench/)
- [C++11](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4304#issuecomment-321431381)

Answer (score 2):

I did some measurements before http://sljit.sourceforge.net/regex_perf.html

Regex engines improved a lot in the last few years, and now you can get high performance regardless of your choice. Although every engine has weaknesses (cases where they perform badly in terms of performance or memory consumption), you get similar performance on common regular expressions.